# Determine where a function is local injective

Tags: multivariable-calculus, proof-verification

I'm studying Multivariate Calculus and I've just studied the inverse theorem and now I'm doing some exercises.

There are some questions about local injectivity that are causing some doubts. For example:

I have to study the local injectivity of this function $f(x,y) = (x^2 + 2xy + y^2,x+y)$, we can conclude that f is a $C^1$ function also the Jacobian of $f$ is given by:
$$
Jf_{(x,y)} =
\begin{bmatrix}
    2x + 2y      & 2x + 2y  \\
    1       & 1\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
then $det(Jf_{(x,y)})=0$ for all $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R^2}$

Therefore, I can't apply the inverse theorem for any point, then It's not possible to conclude local injectivity for any point.

So I've decided to study injectivity of $f(x,y) = ((x+y)^2,x+y)$, and here I conclude that $f$ is not injective because $f(a,b) = f(b,a)$.

I'd like to know, is there any gap in my proof? Is there a easier to do same thing?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You are right that $f$ is not globally injective, since $f(a,b) = f(b,a)$,  but if you want to prove that $f$ is not locally injective you should consider a small neighborhood around a specific point. In other words, can you prove that $f(a+\epsilon, b-\epsilon) = f(a-\epsilon, b+\epsilon)$ for small $\epsilon$?

Comment: oh I've got it. I think since  $\varepsilon $  vanishes when we add $(a + \varepsilon + b - \varepsilon ) = a +b$ same to the other